# Can Java run multiple instances of the same socket in parallel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sockets, callable

I am for-looping multiple socket connections via a Callable with Future Boolean to open sockets to multiple IPs in parallel. If each IP is different, it seems to work fine. However when data needs to be sent to the same IP, a socket is opened multiple times to the same IP, this causes Spring to crash but immediately reboot in a few seconds.

Can Java (Spring) run multiple instances to the same IP, using the same socket? The data is sent fine with no errors either side, except the main Spring thread crashes and restarts during the connection (but this doesn't affect the connection like I mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

One socket holds one TCP connection.

One TCP connection is identified by <source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port>.  Given some bytes that arrive on a wire, that set of 4 numbers is how the TCP implementation decides which "conversation" the bytes belong to. There is no other way.

The upshot is that if you want your client program to have several TCP connections to the same destination, you'll need to have several sockets, and you'll need different source ports (which is generally the case, simply by not specifying a source port when you create the socket).

This is basic TCP and sockets stuff, not Java specific.

Comment: I have physically port forwarded, and opened the relevant single port in the server machine. If I do not specify the source port in the client when a socket is created, I presume connection will be blocked on server side, as the port is not open. Approx 10 connections are trying to be made to the single IP, so is it feasible to open 10 ports on server machine manually, and then assign each connection a new port in client? Or is it better to limit the connection to only 1 at a time? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is simply not possible in TCP to have more than one connection with the same <source addr, source port, dest addr, dest port>. The protocol has no other way to distinguish a connection.  It is not usual to set a source port for TCP; for example, the web browser I am using right now is using an arbitrary source port. Usual firewall setup is to restrict based on destination port only; filtering on source port is mostly unworkable.